# Replace two dots in a string with gsub

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the following code to replace two dots for only one:

```
test<-"test..1"
gsub("\\..", ".", test, fixed=TRUE)
```

and getting:

```
[1] "test..1"
```

I tried several combinations of escape strings, including brackets [] with no success.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are going to use `fixed = TRUE`, use the (non-interpreted) character `.`:

```
> gsub("..", ".", test, fixed = TRUE)
```

Otherwise, within regular expressions (`fixed = FALSE`), `.` has a special meaning (any character) so you'll want to prefix it with a backslash to mean "the dot character":

```
> gsub("\\.\\.", ".", test)
> gsub("\\.{2}", ".", test)
```

Comment: I have become fond of using a character class instead of an escape.  `gsub("[.]{2}", ".", test)`