# Word boundaries handling for punctuation characters in regexp in R

Tags: regex, r, punctuation, word-boundary, word-break

While [Replace two dots in a string with gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523880/replace-two-dots-in-a-string-with-gsub/18524020#18524020) answers the question about replacing punctuation characters like '.', it does not seem to work for word boundaries.  For example,

```
text100 <- "My # is 1234"
text1 <- gsub("\\b#\\b","hash",text100)
> text1
[1] "My # is 1234"
```

The `#` is not getting replaced. How to address this?

Note that multiple #s should not be replaced.  For example,

'##' should NOT be replaced as 'hash' or 'hashhash'.

# followed or preceded by any graph character should
not be replaced (for example, '.#' should not be replaced)

Comment: That won't address the word boundary.  For example:

 text100<-"My number#number # is 1234"
> 
> text1<-gsub("\\#","hash",text100)
> text1
[1] "My numberhashnumber hash is 1234"

Note that number#number should not be replaced.

Comment: Please add the requirement for multiple consecutive hashes replacement to the question  itself.

Comment: @stribizhev Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex does not work because the hash is not a word character and you require a word character to be on both sides of the hash.

If you want to make sure there are no word characters around `#` symbol, use a Perl-style regex replacement:

```
text100 <- "My # is 1234"
gsub("(?<!\\w)\\#+(?!\\w)","hash",text100, perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/ze1Swy)

The look-behind `(?<!\\w)` makes sure there is no letter, digit or underscore before `#`, and the `(?!\\w)` look-ahead makes sure there is no letter, digit or underscore after it.

To avoid overescaping, you may put the hash into a character class:

```
"(?<!\\w)[#]+(?!\\w)"
```

Using `+` quantifier after a hash symbol will make sure multiple consecutive hashes are replaced with one word "hash".

**UPDATE**

A solution that shouls work for your updated example:

```
gsub("(?<!\\w|#)[#](?!\\w|#)", "hash", text100, perl=T)
```

Here, `(?<!\\w|#)` will make sure that a hash is not preceded with a word character or a hash symbol, and the `(?!\\w|#)` negative lookahead will make sure there is no word character or a hash symbol after a hash symbol.

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/VRQ1WA)

Comment: A cruder option would be to catch the adjacent nonword things and put them back in the substitution: `sub("([^\\w])#([^\\w])","\\1hash\\2",text100)`

Comment: @Frank: That is good under one condition: a hash cannot appear at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: @stribizhev While that works for several combinations, it does not seem to work for '##' : 

> text100<-"My number#number # ## #number number# is 1234"
> text1<-gsub("(?<!\\w)[#](?!\\w)","hash",text100,perl=TRUE)
> text1
[1] "My number#number hash hashhash #number number# is 1234"


I don't want '##' to be replaced as hashhash.

Comment: @VenkatRamakrishnan Please add relevant examples to your original post as well. Anyway, `gsub("(?<!\\w|#)[#](?!\\w|#)", "hash", text100, perl=TRUE)` seems to deal with that case.

Comment: @Frank, the original post is self-explanatory. The word boundary should work irrespective of whether the preceding & following character is '#' or not.

Comment: I added the plus (1 or more occurrences) to the regex. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/ze1Swy).

Comment: Oh is it? I think not. This answer dealt with the question as posted. It did not outline the rules but simply said "The # is not getting replaced". You say what you don't want but not what you do want. Should `##` become `hash` or remain as `##`? Who knows?

Comment: @Frank A word boundary technically means it should not be followed or preceded by a alpha-numeric character. Isn't it?  Then, that includes '#'.
That's why '##' should not be replaced as 'hashhash'.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you for the great answer! 1 or more occurances solution is not okay for my context, so Frank's suggestion to add '|#' in the check would be the ideal solution for my situation.

I will give credit to both of your answers.  Thanks both of you so much!

Comment: @stribizhev Feel free to edit my comment into your answer if you think it fits (that's why I commented instead of posting a separate answer). Thanks for the lesson in lookahead/behind, which I'm still learning.

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev. I just figured that it's not just multiple #s that I should be skipping but any graph character preceding or following # that I should be skipping.  I edited my original post to reflect this.

So, instead of '|#', it should be '|[[:graph:]]

Thanks!

Comment: Well, perhaps, you just are looking to use a unicode `\p{L}` (any Unicode letter)? [`gsub("(?<![\\p{L}0-9_]|#)[#](?![\\p{L}0-9_]|#)", "hash", text100, perl=T)`](https://ideone.com/TKeGKM)?